# unit testing a function that returns an object (C# and visual studio)

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing

here is a test function

```
public some_object test_function(some_object obj)
{}
```

and if I use this statement to test this function

```
Assert.AreEqual(some_object, some_object.test_function(obj));
```

where obj is the object of some_object type.

Now how am I supposed to test this function because if I try to use the class name in the expected value parameter of the assert function it gives the error that class function is not valid at this point.

Comment: Please make a distinction betwean classes and instances.

Comment: well `some_object` is a type and `obj` is the object. The function is returning an object of type `some_object`. i fail to understand what is the ambiguity here.

Comment: Your `test_function` is not marked as static yet You use it as such.

Comment: why would i need static. Anyways the problem is solved it seems that i needed an obj instead of just type in the expected value parameter.

Comment: do you want: Assert.IsTrue(some_object.test_function(obj) is some_object)?

Answer (score 0):

```
Assert.AreEqual(some_object, some_object.test_function(obj));
```

`some_object` is a type name

`some_object.test_function(obj)` ia a static methode returning an object

you can not compare a type to an instance.

You can check the type of the returning object to ensure it is of the type some_object, like:

```
Assert.IsTrue(some_object.test_function(obj) is some_object);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find out whether two objects of the same type are equal, you might want to consider overriding equals() method. If you are just trying to find out the object returns is a type of something, you can do something like this:

```
public void IsObjTypeOfSome_objectTest()
{
    bool expected = true;
    bool actual = false;

    /* Assuming that test_function(obj) returns an object type of Some_object */
    if (test_function(obj) is Some_object)
    {
        actual = true;
    }

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```